# xamarin update label been killed by change to a different activity

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, binding

We have a very simple app which reads data over a Bluetooth connection and updates a text string on a page. All the updates work as normal via the timer, but when we switch to a different page in the app and return to the home page, the updates stop working. We can set a break point on the text string update and we can see the new value but it does not update.

Why when we change to a different page and returns does it's stops the updates? It's a simple label and it's been updated in the UI?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Plugin.BLE;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Custom_TestAppHarness
{
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class Homepage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {

    public Homepage()
    {
       

        InitializeComponent();
  
        // Start timer to update all the information on the home activity
        if (App._timeerhasstarted == false)
        {
            App._timeerhasstarted = true;
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    testcall();
                });
                return true; //use this to run continuously 
            });
        }

    }

    void testcall()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            BTTextStatus.Text = App._vehiclefuellevel.ToString();

        });

    }

     protected override void OnAppearing()
     {
        base.OnAppearing();
        BTTextStatus.Text = App._vehiclefuellevel.ToString();

    }

}
}
```

XML code for the label

```
 <Label 
 x:Name = "BTTextStatus"
 Grid.Row="2"
 Grid.Column="0"
 Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
 TextColor="#cccccc"
 FontSize="Medium"/>
```

Comment: `change to a different activity` Do you mean to navigate to other pages? When back to the `Homepage` can this content in `Label` not be changed? I used your code to wirte a demo, it work as normal(I change the mainpage‘s content in the page1), here is running GIF.  https://imgur.com/a/2PAEt6j

Comment: Yes when we change to a different page we cannot update the label i.e. load up app, home screen appears, read the BT data and we can update the label using the timer. But when we switch to a different page and then come back to the home page we cannot update the label. Many thanks for testing my code, odd it's fully working in your demo. It's really odd but it would stop working while switching to a different page.

Comment: You can create a static data, then update ` App._vehiclefuellevel.` in other pages, if it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to move components from the xaml and add them into the .cs file, so the components are references again when the page re-loads. This is the example of label component and you need to add a reference into the xaml grid layout.

```
        MainGrid.Children.Add(lblText = new Label()
        {

            TextColor = Color.FromHex("#cccccc"),
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,

        }, 0, 2);

        Grid.SetColumnSpan(lblText, 6);
```

Add x:name reference into the xaml code so you can insert the components when we re-load the page

```
      <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
```